# How do i change this Powershell script to search by OU rather than user identity

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have this script below that I want to use, however it is setup to search for a single user.

I was hoping for a way to be able to specify by OU instead, but able to also pick an OU on any level?

For example "OU=Clients" would get any and all users in that folder and all users in subfolders under it. - I think powershell does this already but unsure.

````
Function Get-LastLogon {
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
    Returns LastLogon information
    .DESCRIPTION
    Queries the LastLogin information for a user across domain controllers and returns the highest (latest) value
    .EXAMPLE
    Get-LastLogon User
    .EXAMPLE
    Get-LastLogon -Identity User
    .EXAMPLE
    Get-ADUser User | Get-LastLogon
    .EXAMPLE
    Get-LastLogon User1, User2
    .PARAMETER users
    List of users - pipeline can be used
    #>
    
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
    [Parameter(Position= 0,
                Mandatory=$True,
                    ValueFromPipeline=$True,
                        HelpMessage='What user would you like to find the last logon for?')]
    $identity
    )
    
    Begin {}
    
    Process {
    
        Foreach ($account in $identity) {
    
            $dateStamp = $null
            $domainController =$null

            Get-ADDomainController -Filter * | Foreach {

                $dc = $_.HostName
                
                $lastLogon = (Get-ADUser $account -Properties LastLogon -server $dc | Select-Object Name,@{n='LastLogon';e={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogon)}}).Lastlogon
                
                If ($dateStamp -le $lastlogon)
                    {
                    $dateStamp = $lastlogon
                    $domainController = $dc
                    }
                
            } # End of ForEach
        
            $properties = @{
            Name=$account;
            LastLogon=$dateStamp;
            DomainController=$domainController}
        
            New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Prop $properties
        
        } # End of ForEach

    } # End of Process
        
    End {}          
            
} # End of Function
```c
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of using OU as a parameter, then specifying `-SearchBase` to get all the AD users within the OU and its subfolders:

```sh
Function Get-LastLogon {
  param(
    [string]$OUName
  )

  # Get all matching OUs on any level
  $OUs = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter "Name -like '$OUName'"
  $DCs = Get-ADDomainController -Filter *

  # Get all users from each OU from each DC
  $ADUsers = Foreach ($OU in $OUs) {
    Foreach ($DC in $DCs.HostName) {
      Get-ADUser -SearchBase $OU.DistinguishedName -Filter * -Properties LastLogon -server $dc | 
        Select-Object Name,@{n='LastLogon';e={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogon)}}
    }
  }

  # return most recent LastLogon date for each user
  $ADUsers | 
    Group Name | 
    Select Name,@{n='LastLogon';e={$_.Group.LastLogon | sort -desc | select -First 1}}
}  ## End function

Get-LastLogon -OUName 'Clients'
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this, when i run this, depending on how many folders deep it is from the domain, for example the layout in AD is "Domain", then under that there are a few folders, "Builtin", "Clients", and under the Clients folder there are folders under that "Client 1", "Client 2", just as an example.
Depending on how deep the folder is i get more lines of this error:
(comment under this.)

Comment: Get-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'SearchBase'. The argument is null. Provide a valid value for the argument, and then try running 
the command again.
At C:\Users\redacted\Desktop\Get last logon.ps1:13 char:30
+       Get-ADUser -SearchBase $OU.DistinguishedName -Filter * -Propert ...
+                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-ADUser], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser

Comment: @Steve101 Are you running it exactly as written? It's saying the `$OU` object doesn't have a distinguished name property, but it *must* if it was acquired through `Get-ADOrganizationalUnit`

Comment: I did run exactly as you wrote it, then as a test changed "Clients" to a folder name that comes under the "clients" folder in how our AD is setup. It gives the same error but adds another line of the same error in the readout.

Comment: @Steve101 I fixed the parameter name `OU` being the same as the foreach variable. Only caused issues in certain cases, but should work better now...

Comment: That got it, perfect. Thank you!